# (Python) It says Invalid Syntax when i try to run it

Tags: python

I am trying to build a Chat App. There is a Server and Client script. When i run the Server script it brings back an error saying "Invalid Syntax". The error is on the P in the word port. I have tried changing the Word from Port to port but that did not work either. Code is Below. Any Solutions? Thanks

```py
import socket
import sys
import time

x=socket.socket()
h_name= input(Str("Enter the hostname of the server")
Port = 8080
x.connect((h_name,port))
print("Connected to chat server")

while True:
   incoming_message=s.recv(1024)
   incoming _messagge=incoming message.decode()
   print(" Server :", incoming message)
   message= input(str(">>"))
   Message =message.encode()
   s.send(message)
   print(" message has been sent...")
```

Comment: Missing closing paren on the previous line. Plus, `Str` isn't at thing. Python is case-senstive: use `str` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're missing a ) after `h_name= input(Str("Enter the hostname of the server")`

Answer (score 0):

There are the following minor coding mistakes (mainly typo).
Please note that commented with `#`.

```
import socket
import sys
import time

x=socket.socket()
h_name= input(str("Enter the hostname of the server"))  # Missing closing brackets, Str -> str
Port = 8080
x.connect((h_name,Port))  # port -> Port
print("Connected to chat server")
while True:
   incoming_message=x.recv(1024)  # s. -> x.
   incoming_messagge=incoming_message.decode()  # Extra white space and missing '_'
   print(" Server :", incoming_message)  # Missing '_' 
   message=input(str(">>"))
   message=message.encode()  # Message -> message
   x.send(message)  # s. -> x.
   print(" message has been sent...")
```